# MySQL: SET Variable in if exists condition

Tags: mysql, variables, if-statement, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am trying to set the variables while checking the if exists condition.
I have used **:=** to set the variables, however, it for some reason it seems that when I try to set the variable in the if exists condition, it displays the result for the previous query. 
Following is the code snippet from the stored procedure.

```
if exists (select @AccountVerified := AccountVerified, @IsActive := IsActive  from tblUserLookUp where UserName = inUserName) then
        begin
            select "1: From if condition", @AccountVerified, @IsActive;

            select @AccountVerified := AccountVerified, @IsActive := IsActive  from tblUserLookUp where UserName = inUserName;
            select "2: From select condition", @AccountVerified, @IsActive;
            select @AccountVerified, @IsActive;

            if @AccountVerified = 0 then
                set outErrorCode = 3;
            elseif  @IsActive = 0 then
                set outErrorCode = 4;
            end if;
        end;
    else
        set outErrorCode = 1;
    end if;
```

I observed this by trying to print the values through the select statement after the if condition and after again running the select query on the table. 
The

> 2: From select condition

seems to display the actual current results
However,

> 1: From if condition

seems to display the value from previous query.

Is there any concept of variable caching or it is that you cannot set variables in the if condition? I am also open to any other recommendation that you might have.

The only reason to do this is to save that select query on the same table as that of the if exists select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [13.2.10.6 Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> ...
>
> Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it
>   could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL
>   ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference.
>
> ...

An option:

```sql
...
SELECT
  @AccountVerified := AccountVerified,
  @IsActive := IsActive,
  @Exists := TRUE
FROM tblUserLookUp,
     (SELECT
       @AccountVerified := NULL,
       @IsActive := NULL,
       @Exists := FALSE) `init`
WHERE UserName = inUserName;

IF (@Exists) THEN
  ...
ELSE
  ...
END IF;
...
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, man. Seems like a good alternative. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @wchiquito I would expect this to have a second problem... it may preserve old values of the variables if `WHERE` matches nothing, the same way `SELECT ... INTO` does, *viz.* https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207/11651.  They all (or at least `@Exists`) need to be initialized to `NULL` or perhaps `FALSE` before this query runs, since user-defined variables have session scope... because you can get some unexpected seemingly random action at a distance without doing that, even though it always works right the first time it's run on a new connection.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: You're right. Now the variables are initialized. Thanks for the note.